# Understanding Objective-C Reference Notation

Tags: objective-c

Can someone explain the documentation format for Objective-C:

e.g.,

```
+ (id)arrayWithObject:(id)anObject
```

1. Why the plus sign? Why a minus sign in certain circumstances? Can you guys help me understand exactly what the format is when these lines of code appear at the beginning of each task in the reference page?
2. What does it mean when a method is defined like this:

   ```
   -(NSString *)description
   ```
3. Why is the `*` there? Is it a pointer to something? Why is it formatted like that?

Comment: Your questions are about very basic Objective-C constructs, which have little to do with Apple or their documentation. I would recommend checking out some Objective-C tutorials online or in a book.

Comment: Thanks Adam, yea I'm going through an objective C book now which intro'd the concept of the developer resource pages but not much more on the topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @Hollowproc You don't get reputation for voting to close a question, nor by commenting.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I've purged all the Apple-specific language from the post.

Answer (score 3):

> *Why the plus sign? Why a minus sign in certain circumstances?*

A plus sign means that the method is a *class method*. You call it on the *class*, and it returns an instance of the class. So: `+arrayWithObject:` would be called like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:someObject];
```

This creates a single-element instance of an `NSArray*` called `myArray`, which contains a reference to `someObject`.

(For brevity, I'm not going to get into the memory management aspect of this method, except to say that `autorelease` will be called for you at the end of `myArray`'s lifespan. Another variant of this method will return a retained instance of `NSArray*` that you must `release` on your own, which you may prefer if the array needs to live beyond the lifespan of the function it is in. Read through Apple's [*Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), or go through an Objective-C tutorial or book. Understanding how to manage memory is critical for successful Objective-C development.)

A minus sign means that the method is an *instance method*. You call it on an *instance* of the class, and it returns something else, like a number or another object.

As an example, let's say we want to know the number of objects in the instance of `NSArray` we just made. So we call the `-count` method on `myArray`:

```
NSUInteger numberOfObjects = [myArray count];
NSLog(@"there are %u objects in myArray", numberOfObjects);
```

(Note there is no `*` before `NSUInteger`. That is because `NSUInteger` is not an object type, but just another name Apple uses for the `unsigned int` C data type.)

The declaration of the `-count` instance method is:

```
-(NSUInteger)count;
```

which will be explained below.

> *What does it mean when a method is defined like this: ... Why is the * there? Is it a pointer to something? Why is it formatted like that?*

The following method:

```
-(NSString *)description
```

declares that we have an *instance* method called `-description`, which operates on an instance of the class (whatever that class might be, say an `NSArray*` instance) and returns an `NSString*` that gives the `description` of that instance.

Note that this method returns an `NSString*` and not an `NSString`. That's because these functions pass around references or pointers to objects, instead of the objects themselves.

If we call `-description` on `myArray`, assuming it contains `someObject`, then the Xcode console will show a description of `myArray` and its contents:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myArray description]);
```

Note that Apple provides a shortcut where `-description` is called automatically on an object when used with `NSLog()`. So you could also do the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

in order to call `-description` on `myArray`.

Because calling `-description` on an object is redundant in an `NSLog()` statement, this second approach is preferred by Objective-C developers.

Comment: Thanks You so much.. couldn't be more clear now, I kept reading things in the apple reference pages, but without understanding what their formatting meant i was in the dark, it is much clearer now, thank you!!!

Comment: So alex just for further clarification: if I had a particular instance method that look like this:  -(void)addOwnerNamesObject:(NSString *)n; is it correct to understand that this method when called would accept an NSString and set it as an ivar 'n'?

Comment: It accepts an `NSString*`, which you will almost always have. It is unusual to see a non-pointer `NSString`.

Answer (score -1):

1.
'+' means that the function is static while '-' means the function requires an instance.
A static function is one which you don't need an instance and instead call on the class.  Often these are initializers which will return an auto-releasing instance to you.

2.
Yeah, that is because it is a pointer to an NSString objective C object

3.
-(NSString *)description

This means that the class you are looking at the doc for has a method called description which when called on an instance of that class will return a pointer to an NSString object.